# how to delete users on devise as an admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

As an admin I want to delete users from my database. In my view I list all users from my database. When I click the button I want the user to be deleted. I come up with this so far, but it wont give me the right solution. Thx for your time!

This is my view

```
@users.each do |user|

button_to 'Delete User',"#", :controller => "users", :action => "delete_user", :id  => user.id, :confirm  => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete
```

This is my controller:

```
class UsersController < Devise::RegistrationsController

def delete_user
  @deleted_user = User.find(params[:id])
  @deleted_user.destroy
end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a controller (or an action in a exsisting controller )to manage the user model. try to look [here](http://www.tonyamoyal.com/2010/09/29/rails-authentication-with-devise-and-cancan-part-2-restful-resources-for-administrators/) , strip out the cancan part.

have a nice day!

Comment: A new controller like `users_controller`? Does it inherit from a Devise Controller? Or is users_controller taken? So I can put a method like `delete_user` in there?

Comment: yes , Devise dont define users_controller . you could see the devise used controller with "rake routes"

Comment: have you set the right routes ? try to use a REST action the default routing might work.   def destroy ;
    @user = User.find(params[:id]) ;
    @user.destroy ;
end

Comment: no , sorry ... you dont have to exted Devise::RegistrationsController
but simply your Applicationcontroller or an  ActionController::Base ...